# How to parse JSON in background thread after Alamofire request finishes?

Tags: ios, json, swift, multithreading, alamofire

After getting `JSON` data from `Alamofire` request, I want to parse it on background thread, because, parsing process is difficult and has some logic in my case. The first idea to solve was executing a `async` operation on background thread with synchronous request with `Alamofire`. But, as I've read, `Alamofire` works completely asynchronously. The second solution of mine was executing a parsing `JSON` process in another thread after `responseJSON` of `Alamofire` gets called. After it completes, I will update my UI in main thread. Here is how it looks:

```
.responseJSON { (response) in //callback of Alamofire
    if response.result.isSuccess {
        let json = JSON(response.result.value!)
        DispatchQueue(label: "parsing", qos: .userInitiated).async {
            self.parseJSON(json)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.updateUI()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But is it a good approach to solve this problem? I just don't want to parse a `JSON` on main thread, because parsing process has a couple of `for` loops and other operations, and, I think it cause on drawing of UI related stuff.

Comment: Why does Alamofire being asynchronous present an issue? The answer you posted is also fine.

Comment: But, I thought that it would be good if Alamofire had such a function. Because, in my  first option, the idea was creating an another thread for networking. Basically, I don't care is it sync or async in that case, because it doesn't block UI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes  this is a good approach , but you need to make

```
DispatchQueue(label: "parsing", qos: .userInitiated).async {
```

an instance var as crearing a queue is expensive , so try to make it 1 or use the `DispatchQueue.global().async` , you can also use `URLSession.default` that runs in background thread , and consider using `JSONDecoder` instead of swifty json

Comment: I would be happy to use JSONDecoder, but Alamofire currently doesn't support it.

Comment: it does , you can make the response of data instead of json , you can share your problem of json in another relevant question also

Comment: Thanks, for telling this, but the last thing to consider is your suggestion about creating variable for above `queue`. How does that make sense? I execute that code only once. And if I assign that `queue` to some variable, it will not be used anyway.

Comment: if it's 1 request then your current approach is ok , if you have as i expected multiple requests then use global queue

Comment: IMHO, creating a dispatch queue is not that expensive. Far more overhead is in Alamofire's implementation itself, which dispatches _per default_ on the NSOperationQueue.main (which is actually expensive). The better approach is to tell Alamofire to use a different queue when invoking the completion handler, like @JonShier suggested. Using one of the standard global dispatch queues is the fastest way to dispatch closures and also the most "economic" and is also most UI friendly.

Answer (score 3):

Alamofire's `response` methods take a `queue` parameter, so you can control where the closure is run:

```
responseJSON(queue: myQueue) { (response) 
    ...
}
```

Just make sure you call back to the main queue.

Also, if you want to use `JSONDecoder`, update to Alamofire 5 (currently in beta) or use `responseData` and feed that data into `JSONDecoder`.

Answer (score 1):

This is perfect. It's a well respected approach to this type of task.

It show's how flexible and easy to use GCD (grand central dispatch) is.

There is nothing wrong with nested GCD calls to dispatch.